# Random for any database Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`PostgreSQL` requires `random()` and `MySQL` requires `rand()` is there any way to write query for both databases in Rails way?

On localhost I'm using PostgreSQL, on development MySQL, the query is:

```
@texts = Text.where('status is true and id != ?', @text.id).limit(3).order("RANDOM()")
```

Comment: Calculate in ruby using [the Random class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Random.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below,

```
 case ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
  when 'PostgreSQL'
     @texts = Text.where('status is true and id != ?', @text.id).limit(3).order("RANDOM()") 
  else
     @texts = Text.where('status is true and id != ?', @text.id).limit(3).order("rand()") 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset to your advantage to find a random record independently from your database.

```
Text.offset(rand(Text.count)).first
```